# In Wildfly 8 or 9 in standalone.xml why is the JPA version 1.1?

Tags: jpa, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am working with WildFly 9.0.1.Final release and noticed this line in the `standalone.xml`:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
    <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
</subsystem>
```

I know that JPA version thats shipped with WildFly 9 is 2.1, so what does the value jpa:1.1 refer to here?

Comment: There is no JPA 1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1` is the namespace for the XML configuration of the JPA subsystem in WildFly. In your WildFly installation, the corresponding schema is located at `docs/schema/jboss-as-jpa_1_1.xsd`.

The versioning of subsystem schemas is not related to the versioning of any Java EE specs.